# Android render and logic threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

On the Android platform, how would I separate the rendering from the logic?
I can get a basic custom thread class doing the drawing but what I don't get is where to put the logic update.
Doing some research, I think it would be best to use two different threads one for each, rendering and logic updating.
All I can think of atm is to updatelogic with the onDraw in the same thread.
Any pointers to tutorials or some insight on the matter would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want the logic and rendering happening at the same time? This could cause problems in your game.

Comment: Uhhh, well as I understand it, you would have your logic updated whenever it should(when player presses "up" to move the player "up"/forward) and the render the updated graphics/sprite position. But the call to update logic should not be in the same thread where the rendering takes place.

Comment: semajhan, games that have physics in them do not just update based on user input - they also update based on time elapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed one of the most downloaded games on the android marketplace, but it's been 2 years since then so this solution may be obsolete.  What I did was:
- use a View object as the content view
- override the draw() method of that View object's class
- at the end of the draw() method, call doLogic()

Notice that both the rendering and the doLogic() call happen in the main thread.  This sounds like a no-no, but it works for most games (and gives you automatic synchronization without having to get complicated).